# Django "NoReverseMatch" Error

Tags: django, url

I'm working with django and there's the relevant code in my HTML file:

```
<form action="{% url 'users: check' %}" method="post">
```

I'm hoping that the form's data be sent to the method "check" in a app named users.
In `/user` folder there's `urls.py` with relevant code:

```
app_name = users
urlpatterns = [
    path('check', views.check, name='check'),
]
```

And there's indeed a method called check in my `views.py`. But when I tried to get to the website I got the ERROR:

> NoReverseMatch at /users/login
>
> Reverse for ' check' not found. ' check' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I can't figure out what's the problem. Everything seems to be set well.

Django version is 2.0 and Python 3.4.

Comment: post your `urls.py` and `views.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="{% url 'users:check' %}" method="post">
```

you cant give space after `:` in the url

or if its the same page where you are POSTING data

then you can simply use this

```
<form action="" method="post">
```